# How do I add file details like version, product name, company, etc when creating an exe file from javascript file using pkg?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, metadata, executable

I have a javascript file and I converted it into an executable using [pkg](https://github.com/vercel/pkg).

Here is the npm script:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "build": "pkg index.js --target node16-win-x64 --output pn.exe"
  },
```

And after generating the exe file, the default file details are applied like this:

[image]

How do I change those values (file description, file version, product name, etc.) using pkg?

If it is impossible to do with the pkg package, can you please recommend any other ways/tools to do that?

Comment: You can edit them afterwards, for example using Resource Hacker. You can do it manually or using its CLI.